# How to access a ID across QML files

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick

I am not getting how to access a ID from one QML to another QML.

**NOTE:** QML files are located in different directory ,Below is the code:

**//QML1.qml**

```
Rectangle
{
    property alias rect1:rect1
    property string title:"some text"
    id:rect1
}
```

**//QML2.qml**

```
Text
{
   text:rect1.title //**ERROR** ReferenceError: rect1 is not defined
}
```

**[EDIT 1]** : Folder Structure:

```
|- Main Directory
     |- QML1 Directory
     |- QML2 Directory
```

**[EDIT 2]**: **//Main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow
{
   id:window
   width:600
   height:400
   QML2
   {
      //Code goes here and I need to access QML1 variable without initializing it. 
   }
}
```

Comment: You can display the folder structure.

Comment: @eyllansec I have added the folder structure .pls check

Comment: QML ID's are only locally defined. You should show the code where QML1 and QML2 are created. Note that you can create multiple instances of a single QML file, therefore it would be impossible to uniquely identify an object in this way. The only exception are [singleton](http://wiki.qt.io/Qml_Styling#Approach_2:_Style_Singleton) objects.

Comment: @m7913d - not entierly. In some cases you can access `id`s that are defined outside, even without having singletons flying around... But let's wait for the necessary code of *@pra7* first :D

Comment: @derM ..I have edited my question, pls check. and how to access objects that without singleton?

Comment: @pra7 - where is QML1 instantiated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What matters when using ids is not file system structure but instance structure.

Think of ids like something that is source specific, in the general case you should try and limit usage to this paradigm.

But ids actually go a little further that this. Depending on the instance tree structure, you can access a parent id object from a child source, provided you have the guarantee the child is always going to be instantiated with that particular parent. I discovered this while streamlining QML files, right clicking on an object tree inside a QML file and selecting "move component to a separate file", that the newly created file retained access to the parent object via id.

Consider that there are additional ways to access objects in QML. For example, properties, defined in the root object of a source are defacto dynamic scope properties, so they can be looked up from an object that exists nested directly or indirectly into that object, as long as the property doesn't get shadowed by another identically named one.

Naturally, if you deal with "global" objects, singleton is always the way to go, as it should in theory be the fastest and most efficient way to locate an object.